# db2 security issue

Tags: db2

I tried this from a client:

connect to db from shell with a random user like this

> db2 connect to remotenode

no user or using ...

then i m logged in and can do

> db2 describe tables for schema xxx

I m not allowed to query any tables . thank god .

How can i prevent this? anyone can browse the tables

Comment: Better asked on ServerFault, no?

Answer (score 3):

Have your DBA tighten security on the database.  The most obvious method for this would be to revoke CONNECT privilege from public.

However, if you want to prevent even users who are authorized to connect to a database from seeing which tables exist in the database, the DBA would need to revoke SELECT privilege on some of the system catalog tables (i.e. tables in the SYSCAT and SYSIBM schemas).

Answer (score 0):

`revoke connect from public`, I think is what you need.